# Lazy loading broken on prod build Angular 8

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm trying to get my lazy loaded routes to work in production. Currently, everything works fine in development mode but when I switch to AOT I get the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'routeConfig' of undefined`

I've got this error reproduced in a tiny test project with a minimal amount of code. My lazy loaded modules look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'lazy',
        loadChildren: () => import('./lazy-loaded-component/lazy-loaded.module').then(m => m.LazyLoadedModule)
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true}),
        FormsModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

lazy-loaded.module:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {LazyLoadedComponent} from "./lazy-loaded.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LazyLoadedComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    declarations: [LazyLoadedComponent]
})
export class LazyLoadedModule {
}
```

My versions look like this:

```
Angular CLI: 8.1.2
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.1.2
... animations, cli, common, compiler, core, elements, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, upgrade

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.801.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.801.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.801.2
@angular-devkit/core              8.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.1.2
@angular/compiler-cli             8.2.0-next.2
@ngtools/webpack                  6.2.9
@schematics/angular               8.1.2
@schematics/update                0.801.2
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.35.2
```

The original error that I was getting was `Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded with production configuration` when I was using our custom webpack build. I have since switched to using the CLI and now the error has changed. I'm not sure if that information would be helpful but I figure the more info the better.

I've tried clearing out `node_modules`, I've tried `npm install acorn`, I've tried removing all old webpack plugins and loaders to try and eliminate colliding webpack versions, I've tried the old Angular v7 string syntax for lazy loading, and many other things.

***Update*** I just tried creating a completely fresh Angular application and reproduced the error: `Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded`

Comment: if you dont 'useHash', does it work?

Comment: You problem could come from `LazyLoadedModule` configuration and module routing. Can you add it to you question please ?

Comment: @MartinChoraine I have added that code above!

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli removing the `useHash` property does not fix the issue.

Comment: could you add `{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}` in main module as a provider

Comment: @PranavRamachandran added that and the error persists

Comment: try with `"module": "esnext"` &  `"target": "es2015"` in tsconfig.json  file  in compileOptions.
my compile cli version in package.json is `"@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2"` , try downgrading your version to 8.1.2 too

Comment: @PranavRamachandran my tsconfig already had those settings. I tried downgrading my cli version and that didn't work. Interestingly, I downloaded the Angular Docs lazy loading example project and used those dependencies in the package.json in my fresh cli project and the error has gone away. I am going to try and track down the exact dependency that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after downloading the [Angular sample lazy loading project](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) and using the dependencies found in the `package.json` in that project I was able to fix this error. I've downgraded all of my `@angular/` packages to `^8.0.0` and also set `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.800.0"` once I did that my lazy loading started working again. I think the issue is coming from the `@angular-devkit/build-angular` package's most recent version but I can't be sure.

I hope this helps someone, I would be happy to post any other supporting code if someone else gets stuck!