# Angular: Cannot read property 'routeConfig' of undefined TypeError

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

When I am running my project locally everything works fine. I did a build of my project using:

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer --base-href /ProjectName/
```

When I run this code online. I can see my header and my footer. But my main page is not showed. If i click on the nav bar to go to another page I get this error:

```
main.1414f458336b0098f411.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'routeConfig' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'routeConfig' of undefined
    at Qd.shouldReuseRoute (main.1414f458336b0098f411.js:1)
    at main.1414f458336b0098f411.js:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at main.1414f458336b0098f411.js:1
    at e (main.1414f458336b0098f411.js:1)
    at main.1414f458336b0098f411.js:1
    at j.project (main.1414f458336b0098f411.js:1)
    at j._next (main.1414f458336b0098f411.js:1)
    at j.next (main.1414f458336b0098f411.js:1)
    at gu.notifyNext (main.1414f458336b0098f411.js:1)
    at j (polyfills.12f318da3477f20d33b8.js:1)
    at j (polyfills.12f318da3477f20d33b8.js:1)
    at polyfills.12f318da3477f20d33b8.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.12f318da3477f20d33b8.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.1414f458336b0098f411.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.12f318da3477f20d33b8.js:1)
    at t.runTask (polyfills.12f318da3477f20d33b8.js:1)
    at g (polyfills.12f318da3477f20d33b8.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.12f318da3477f20d33b8.js:1)
    at _ (polyfills.12f318da3477f20d33b8.js:1)
```

App Component:

```
<div id="page-container" class="sidebar-o side-scroll page-header-fixed main-content-boxed">
  <app-header></app-header>

</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Header Component:

```
<nav id="sidebar">
  blablabla
</nav>
<!-- END Sidebar -->

<!-- Header -->
<header id="page-header">
  <!-- Header Content -->

    BLABLABLA
</header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './interceptors/token.interceptor';
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
import { AllExamsComponent } from './all-exams/all-exams.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { AddQuestionComponent } from './add-question/add-question.component';
import { ExamSimulatorService } from './services/exam-simulator.service';
import { ResultsComponent } from './results/results.component';
import { ExamComponent } from './exam/exam.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AddSoftwareComponent } from './add-software/add-software.component';
import { FinishedComponent } from './finished/finished.component';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AllExamsComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    AddQuestionComponent,
    ResultsComponent,
    ExamComponent,
    AddSoftwareComponent,
    FinishedComponent


  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DataTablesModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule



  ],
  providers: [
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ExamSimulatorService,
    AuthService,
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AllExamsComponent } from './all-exams/all-exams.component';
import { AddQuestionComponent } from './add-question/add-question.component';
import { ExamComponent } from './exam/exam.component';
import { AddSoftwareComponent } from './add-software/add-software.component';
import { FinishedComponent } from './finished/finished.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/allExams', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'allExams', component: AllExamsComponent },
  { path: 'addQuestion', component: AddQuestionComponent },
  { path: 'exam/:software', component: ExamComponent },
  { path: 'addSoftware', component: AddSoftwareComponent },
  { path: 'finished', component: FinishedComponent }


];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<html lang="en" class="no-focus lt-ie10 lt-ie10-msg"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-focus">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

  <title>Exams</title>     

  <base href="/">   

</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "exam-simulator-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.11",
    "angular-datatables": "^8.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.20",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.11",
    "@schematics/angular": "^7.3.9",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.18",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please put the code that cause the problem.

Comment: Also please include the code in the index.html files. Or, please try to use the same baseHref that you have set in the index.html when you're building in prod mode.

Comment: I already tried doing the base href the same as my build href but it does not work

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` contents?

Comment: Are you using `ActivatedRoute` anywhere?

Comment: I added the package.json in the code. And yes i use activatedRoute in one component. BUt I have injected it in my constructor, and local it is working. Just on the server I am having troubles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the `@angular-devkit/build-angular` version. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57209932/12431728) to a similar question, where they said:

> I've downgraded all of my `@angular/` packages to `^8.0.0` and also set `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.800.0"` once I did that my lazy loading started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but can you try with this

```
ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --base-href /ProjectName/
```

[image]

Comment: @RobinMedland Please can you try one more time without base href and put this ` { path: '**', redirectTo: '/allExams', pathMatch: 'full' },` at end of in your routes array

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody else comes to this question, after creating new pipe:

It looks like when you create new pipe by copying it from existing one and forget to change the name in decorator:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'initials',
})
```

so you've got two pipes with the same `name` your app will fail with exactly the same problem as mentioned above.

Happened to me twice, on two different projects, I had to revert versions of packages and even did `git reset --hard` not knowing what it was, but this time versions were not changed for over 3 months and app was working 5 minutes before, thus I found the culprit.